# How can I get the current top-level object that is being serialized?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm building a `CustomCreationConverter` subclass that deserializes objects that have a dependence on their containing object:

```
public interface IFoo {
    public int Id { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IBar> Bars { get; }
}

public interface IBar {
    public int Id { get; }
    public IFoo Parent { get; }
}

public class BarDeserializer : CustomCreationConverter<IBar>
{
    private class Bar : IBar
    {
        public Int Id { get; set; }
        public IFoo Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public override IBar Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Bar();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var b = (Bar) Create(objectType);
        b.Id = JToken.Load(reader).Value<int>();
        b.Parent = ??? // can I get the IFoo from anything in this context?

        return b;
    }
}
```

I don't see anything in `JsonSerializer` that will give me the `IFoo` instance that's currently being deserialized.  Is it there and I'm missing it, or is there any other way to get it?

Comment: That's surely no C question. Please edit your tags

Comment: It surely is not - not sure why it came up as [c] instead of [c#].  Thanks for calling it out.